# How to put an image link in PHP script

Tags: php

I'm writing a CMS that user can post some news and comments. I have problems with images. would like to place all images of all posts in one folder and access them by post ID and image ID (starting from 0 for each post)

The only thing I can't manage to do is producing image links in script. I saw some pages on net doing same thing. like this:

```
<img src=https://www.somewhere.com/uploads/image.php?postid=20&id=80>
```

**EDIT:** to clarify, supposing there is an image in `http://www.somewhere.com/uploads/1_2.jpg` how script can pass the image when `https://www.somewhere.com/uploads/image.php?postid=x&id=y` is the source of img tag in somewhere?

Comment: You can take the image location from db with the 'postid=20 & id=80' then echo it in the src. That will be simple.

Comment: so in the source of HTML page the real location will be appear correct? I don't it to be shown on page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $_GET['postid'] and $_GET['id'] you can read the requested postid and id as variables in images.php, and then return the header and the raw image data. Just a simple example, that you can explore:

```
<?php

$postid = $_GET['postid'];
$id = $_GET['id'];

header("Pragma: public");
header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
header("/var/www/img/".$postid."_".$id.".jpg");
readfile('/var/www/img/'.$postid.'_'.$id.'.jpg');

?>
```

I hope this will help you.

**EDIT:** You can use the postid and id to get the location of the image from a database etc.